# Why does images.google.com GET requests have such an un-readable form?

Tags: java, javascript, php

Particularly, what are all the dots and numbers at the end for.

Here is an example:

```
https://www.google.com/search?site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1366&bih=673&q=kale&oq=kale&gs_l=img.3..0l10.403.1120.0.1352.4.4.0.0.0.0.407.543.0j1j4-1.2.0....0...1ac.1.32.img..2.2.542.vC-f2Kfx-2E
```

It is a GET variables value, but why such a strange un-human readable syntax?

I assume they are using PHP or Java on the back-end.

Comment: My hunch is that it's a compressed string of arguments given the max length of HTTP GET's in older browsers.

Comment: @Jason - I believe you.  But why so many arguments?  I as the user produce one variable.  `user_submission_string=kale`.  Everything else should be a default value.  And why would a compression contain so many dots, are you suggesting they are delimeters of sorts.  Please elaborate in an answer and I will mark it.

Comment: I know that when doing a search through the google search in outbox in Firefox it will append some user agent stuff (for tracking), maybe image search is using a more advanced (or harder to spoof) version if that. Or it could be a session value. I have an interview with Google in a few weeks, maybe the fact that it is unreadable to me means I'm not Google material :)

Comment: These are just guesses and hardly qualify for being voted up or selected as correct :)

Comment: As for the back end, it's definitely not PHP (PHP is not one of "official" google languages) and not Java either, as java is way too slow.  Most likely it's compiled C/C++.

Comment: It's just tracking data.

Answer (score -1):

What you are seeing is *internal computer data*, not exactly intended for normal human consumption, but there for a good reason.  Also perhaps you are thinking, why would anyone want these ugly internal details displayed on the average user's screen?

When HTTP was invented the thought was that GET requests should be *stateful*, in other words, if I copy a URI from my browser and email it to you, and you browse to it, then you should see exactly what I saw.  To make this work the GET data needed to be in the URI and not hidden from view.  Thus the dirty details you are seeing.  Back in the day they were thinking of simple GET queries, for example: **http://www.somedomain.com/Search?Find=FooBar**

However, as software has evolved more data needs to be passed with GET requests and unfortunately it is all visible in the URI.  (Note that this also becomes a minor security hole because the average user can see some of the internals of web page production and easily tamper with it.)

What is needed is a hidden data passing method for GET type queries to clean up URIs when it is not necessary for these details to be present.  A proposal for such an improvement to HTTP is in the process of being considered.  It would involve adding a new method to HTTP similar to GET but with hidden data passing like POST.

Comment: Parameters send with POST are readable like parameters send with GET requests. With POST the parameters are just moved to the HTTP content part instead of being in the URL with GET. This is NOT a security improvement in any case. There are good reasons to use POST over GET and the other way around, but `security` is NOT one of these reasons.

Comment: I disagree with you.  There are hackers at all skill levels.  A privacy fence provides some degree of privacy even if one who is tall can look over it.  Security needs to be dealt with from all angles and levels I think.  Forgetting to simply shut the door, even when it can be easily opened, can allow some things to slip by.

Comment: The point is not that some may see parameters in the body part and some may not. It does not matter if they see them, because parameters are public between client and server. They are allowed to see and change them and this is not a security issue. It becomes a security issue when you do not validate  that (possibly "tampered") user input on server side.

You may want to validate it on client side for usability reasons. But you must validate them on server side for security reasons.

Comment: I think in a perfect world you are indeed correct, and yes I am very careful to validate all inputs.  But the world is imperfect, as are we.  And mistakes can be made.  So the way I try to operate is to provide layers of security, not a single wall.  Although validating inputs will protect them, hiding them from plain view may keep some internal details a bit more private and so not give an attacker any ideas of how to approach things.  That is all I was saying.